# Can I customize Devise's Registration Controller without creating my own set of views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have  my `app/views/devise` views, and all I want to do is be able to pass a few instance variables into my `edit.html.erb`.

Is there a way for me to do that without having to move my `registrations/edit.html.erb` to another folder?

**Edit 1**

This is what I have done.

`app/views/users/registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    if current_user_subscribed?
      @plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(current_user.plan_name)
    end
    super
  end
end
```

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    invitations: 'invitations',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
    },
    path_names: { :sign_up => "register",
                  :sign_in => "login",
                  :sign_out => "logout",
                  :settings => "settings" }
```

This is my `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`:

```
<% if current_user_subscribed? %>
  <div class="col-md-12 subscribed-card">
    <%= render partial: "subscriptions/card_brand", locals: { brand: current_user.card_brand, plan: @plan } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my `app/views/subscriptions/_card_brand.html.erb`

```
<div class="payment-card">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Subscribed To: <%= plan.name %> for <%= formatted_price(plan.amount) %></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is the error I am getting:

```
NoMethodError at /settings
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

**Edit 2**

This is my server log, which doesn't seem to be sending the request to `Users::RegistrationsController` like I would want:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
  User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/devise
  Role Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'coach') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 7]]
  School Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."school_type" IN (1, 2)
  Rendered subscriptions/_card_brand.html.erb (12.2ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/devise (904.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 994ms (ActiveRecord: 35.1ms)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to expand on the default behaviour of the `Devise::RegistrationsController`, without moving the files around.

The easiest solution in my opinion would be to inherit the registrations controller into a new class and override the controller used.

Start by creating a new controller, let's say `RegistrationsController` -> `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`.

Inherit the `Devise::RegistrationsController` to keep all behaviours and views and add your code to `edit` action under `super`.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    super
    @my_instance = "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Then point devise's routes to the correct registrations controller.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Now you should have access to your instance within `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`.

https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/2343176

**OP Edit**

Make sure to specify the `devise_scope` to the right path:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "settings", to: "users/registrations#edit"
  end
```

Which is based on the fact that my version gets routed to the controller `users/registrations`.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but it doesn't work. Hang on, I am going to update the question with my code and show you.

Comment: I'm sure that this should work, I've done this before. Can't test right now, but will later.

Comment: I did, didn't see any mistakes.

Comment: That's what I am saying. So strange!

Comment: This eventually worked. The issue was that `@plan` was `nil` because it kept rendering `Devise::Registrations#Edit` and not `Users::Registration#Edit`. Once I changed the route `get "settings", to: "devise/registrations#edit"` to `get "settings", to: "users/registrations#edit"` and then I made sure to put `super` below my `if` statement....it worked.